# How to validate a two-step form?

Tags: php, validation, input

I am validating an input of the user registration form that consists of two pages. If `$_POST` input passes the validation then `$valid` variable is set to `true`.

How to take user to the second registration form only if first registration form is validated successfully (ie. `$valid` is eq. to `true`)?

Comment: why dont you use javascript for client site validation, will be great deal of help for registration process

Comment: Pretty hard to say anything without seeing the code, other than that you should send the user to the second step immediately if the submitted data is valid, but you knew that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the form using Javascript instead, then in your form add `onsubmit="validateForm()"` and your `validateForm()` function returns true or false.  If it returns false the form will not submit.

If you want to validate with PHP, you do have to submit the form first, and if invalid you redirect back to the original form page but you'll have to re-set the submitted values.  What I would do is first instantiate all your variables for the form fields at the top of the page and set with blank values.  Then have a section check for a flag like valid=false and if so, update those variables with posted values.

For example:

```
<?php
$first_name = '';
$last_name = '';
$email = '';
$phone = '';
$valid = true;

// Check if valid:
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    // Validate string and if bad valid = false.
    $valid = false;

    // Set value from $_POST;
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // Perform validation.

    $valid = true;  // else false

    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

// Check valid flag.
if (!valid) {
    // Display some error to the user.
    $message = 'There was something wrong.';
} else {
    // Tedirect to the destination page.
    // header(..);
}
```

Then set values of the fields with variables at top of page:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?=echo $first_name?>">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?=echo $last_name?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?=echo $email?>">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?=$phone?>">
</form>
```

Beware that the above example is for illustration purposes of the logic only. It exposes [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and other types of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Upon receiving `$_POST` and passing the validation redirect user using [header](http://php.net/header) to the 2nd registration page.

And before doing that do update the value of $valid to `true` either

1. In `$_SESSION` and access it on the 2nd registration page
2. or if you want you can put it as a GET parameter by appending it `header('Location: http://example.com/2ndregistrationstep.php?valid=true')`

Comment: You should not pass the state of the form as a GET parameter because user can change it. If you are relying on the session state, make sure that you are handling the case of expired session.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you print the registration form directly in your script. Why not add simple logic:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
    // .. validate, and then 
    $_SESSION['valid'] = TRUE; // or FALSE
}

if (empty($_SESSION['valid'])) {
    // .. print first step
} else {
    // .. print second step
}
```